# How to extract single image (with different name each time) from multiple videos in the one folder using ffmpeg bash script

Tags: linux, image, bash, video, ffmpeg

Let's start with this... I'm fairly new to Linux.

I have been looking into ffmpeg to extract an image from a video using the terminal. I've accomplished this using this piece of code:

```
   ffmpeg  -itsoffset -4  -i oggvideo.ogg -vcodec mjpeg -vframes 1 -an -f rawvideo -s 320x240 oggThumb.jpg
```

I run this when I'm in the directory which holds the videos in my project. But what I want is to extract an image from all videos in that folder at the same time, naming the image corresponding with the video name it's extracted from. My end goal is to have a folder which will hold videos that a user uploads, and at a certain time the script will run and extract images from the uploaded videos, saving the image path to a database.

I found this line of code:

```
for %%i in (*.mp4) do ffmpeg -ss 20 -i %%i -t 1 -s 590x340 -f image2 %%i.jpg
```

from this site: [Trying-to-extract-1-image-from-multiple-videos-with-FFMPEG](http://forum.videohelp.com/threads/355192-Trying-to-extract-1-image-from-multiple-videos-with-FFMPEG)

I run that in the  terminal and it gives me the error: 'bash: syntax error near unexpected token `(''
I tried removing the '( )' but then it just takes me onto a new line. This is where I'm having the most problems due to being relatively new to linux commands.

Any suggestions or advice would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I rewrote your command

```
for i in *.mp4 
do
    echo Processing "$i" # Just to visually keep track of what's going on
    ffmpeg -ss 20 -i "$i" -t 1 -s 590x340 "${i%.mp4}".jpg
done
```

Please note:

1. `ffmpeg` might produce warnings and/or errors while processing. This command simply ignore them.
2. I quoted all occurrences of the variable `i` in order to deal with spaces in filenames.
3. I use the (bash) *remove matching suffix operator* (`${parameter%word}`) to remove filename extension as it is its own purpose
4. I rewrote your statement as a multi-line expression in order to make it more readable (to my taste). If for some reason you want to rewrite it as one-liner, please add a `;` both at the end of the first, third and fourth lines.
5. I removed the `-f image2` option (part of your initial command) as it probably does *not* what you want. [`image2` is for *demuxing image*](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-2) not *extracting* them.

Other issues concerning `ffmpeg` by itself would better be discussed on http://superuser.com .
Concerning your specific needs, see https://superuser.com/a/302203/224101 for example.

---

**EDIT:** If you're comming from Windows environment, be aware that most Unix-like filesystems are case sensitives. A fale named "XXX.MP4" will not match by default the glob pattern "*.mp4".

If this is your issue, using `bash` you might force case insensivity using `shopt -s nocaseglob`. Use `shopt -u nocaseglob` to revert to normal behavior.

Here is an example on my system (ext4 fs):

```
sh$ touch a.mp4
sh$ touch B.MP4
sh$ touch C.Mp4
sh$ touch D.mp4

# default settings
sh$ ls *.mp4
a.mp4  D.mp4

# force case insensitive glob
sh$ shopt -s nocaseglob 
sh$ ls *.mp4
a.mp4  B.MP4  C.Mp4  D.mp4

# force case sensitive glob (back to defaults)
sh$ shopt -u nocaseglob 
sh$ ls *.mp4
a.mp4  D.mp4
```

Comment: It's still only taking the first mp4 video. I'll see if I can get it working from there. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @morriscotty_sd If some files are *not* processed, either `ffmpeg` just can't process them (badly encoded?). Some distributions switched from `ffmpeg` to `avconv` recently -- this might has its share of incompatibilities. Or maybe the various filenames does not match the *.mp4 glob pattern because of case sensitivity. I've edited my answer to point out that later _potential_ issue.

Comment: @morriscotty_sd BTW, you don't want [`-f image2`](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-2) here !!!

Comment: I've just realised something very stupid. The video that isn't producing the image is only 5 seconds long therefore -ss 20 won't output an image!! Completely works now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That one-liner you posted there looks like Windows shell code.

An equivalent bash translation (although your command and parameters may vary) would look like:

```
for i in $(ls *.mp4); do ffmpeg -ss 20 -i $i -t 1 -s 590x340 -f image2 ${i//.mp4/}.jpg; done
```

Comment: I believe it would be better to use `for i in *.mp4` than to parse the output of `ls` which is considered bad practice.

Comment: does that work for you? I'm not sure bash works that way :) Also, why is it a "bad practice" ? ls is part of the GNU coreutils!

Comment: That is exactly how bash works - it is one of the strengths of bash! `ls` output is arranged for humans, computers have better ways of knowing what is in directories. Try pasting your code in here http://www.shellcheck.net/#  Also, have a read here http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Practices Then think about filenames with spaces and newlines in them.

Comment: This extracted an image from one of my mp4 videos but not any other. It shows this error in the terminal: '[image2 @ 0x217ce20] Could not get frame filename number 2 from pattern 'newcampusnewlearning.jpg'    
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Input/output error' but it did still extract an image from the newcampuslearning video.

Comment: By the way, you should also add double quotes around `$i`, like this `"$i"`.

Comment: @LiviuChircu `for i in $(ls *.mp4); ...` will fail if there is spaces in some file names.

Comment: Wow, thanks! I just did a `for i in *.xxxx; do echo "$i"; done`, and since it printed `*.xxxx`, I thought it was invalid syntax! Thank you @SylvainLeroux and @MarkSetchell!